# jquery animation not working in IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a script that when a button is clicked that button rotates, the opacity changes and a paragraph slidetoggles.  I know the rotate won't happen because it uses the webkit features, but I'd still like the opacity to change and the paragraph to open and these should happen in IE 8 but for some reason doesn't.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
var effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO = {
    "-webkit-transition": "webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out"
};
$("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO").css(effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO);


var effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG = 0;

$("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO").toggle(function() {
$("p#effects_of_yoga_2010_TEXT").slideDown("250");
effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG += 45;
effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO.style.setProperty('-webkit-transform', 'rotateZ(' +   
effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG + 'deg)');
$("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO").fadeTo("250", 0.65);
}, function() {
$("p#effects_of_yoga_2010_TEXT").slideUp("250");
effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG += 45;
effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO.style.setProperty('-webkit-transform', 'rotateZ(' +  
effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG + 'deg)');
$("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO").fadeTo("250", 0.3);
});
```

Comment: You are mixing plain JS with jQuery. `document.getElementById('effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO');` is plain JS, which is much shorter in jQuery, namely: `$("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO");`

Comment: this would prevent IE from working?  it works fine in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've provided a jsFiddle, when I run your code, I see it throw an exception in IE8 because the `style.setProperty()` method does not exist.  Thus the rest of the toggle function does not run.  If I temporarily comment the `setProperty()` lines out, the `.fadeTo()` works in IE8.

So, why don't use just use jquery's `.css()` method instead of `.setProperty()` to set those style parameters and then you don't have to worry about browsr compatibility.

For example:

```
$("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO").css("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out");
```

---

Use `.fadeTo()` instead of `.animate()` and jQuery will use the proper filter value for the opacity setting in older versions of IE.  See the [jQuery doc on fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) for more info.

Here's an example using `.toggle()` and `.fadeTo()` that works in IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/29JUB/

Comment: unfortunately it's just that none of the buttons do anything, I made all of the changes for the first button and still nothing, but it works in chrome fine.  Here is the fiddle I have it in, it's the first button, the first plus sign that I made all of the changes suggested here for.  http://jsfiddle.net/loriensleafs/TMGv3/23/  not sure why it's still not working in IE.

Comment: @loriensleafs - now that you've provided a jsFiddle, see the error I see in IE8 (added to the beginning of my answer above).

Comment: so are these two thing the same:  var effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO = document.getElementById('effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO');
effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out");

var effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO = {
  "-webkit-transition": "webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out"};  
  $("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO").css(effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO);

Comment: @loriensleafs - they do the same thing except that the jQuery method will not cause errors in IE8.

Comment: so when I do it this way the button no loner rotates, I did this

Comment: effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO = {
  "-webkit-transition": "webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out"};  
  $("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO").css(effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO);


var effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG = 0;

$("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO").toggle(function() {
    $("p#effects_of_yoga_2010_TEXT").slideDown("250");
  effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG += 45;
  effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO.style.setProperty('-webkit-transform', 'rotateZ('+effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG+'deg)'); 
    $("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO").fadeTo("250", 0.65); 
},

Comment: function() {
  $("p#effects_of_yoga_2010_TEXT").slideUp("250");
  effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG += 45;
  effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO.style.setProperty('-webkit-transform', 'rotateZ('+effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG+'deg)');  
  $("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO").fadeTo("250", 0.3);
});

Comment: @loriensleafs - multiline code is unreadable in comments.  You will have to add it to the end of your question and refer to it from a comment to make it understandable.  I cannot understand the code in your comments.

Comment: sorry about that, thanks for being patient with me, added the code to the top there, lost the rotation on the button when I click it, everything else works, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a toggle function inside a toggle function, this won't work properly. Try [`slideUp`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [`slideDown`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) instead.

As jfriend00 said, you can use the [fadeTo](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) property for easy opacity changes!

Comment: slideToggle inside of a toggle function shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: unfortunately it's just that none of the buttons do anything, I made all of the changes for the first button and still nothing, but it works in chrome fine. Here is the fiddle I have it in, it's the first button, the first plus sign that I made all of the changes suggested here for. jsfiddle.net/loriensleafs/TMGv3/23 not sure why it's still not working in IE.